# Best data grid for php based application using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, grid

What is the best data grid for php based application using ajax? Any reference please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) plugin. I can bet you will love it. I have used it often, and the documentation is also available in [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php).

Hope it helps. As for any problems with this plugin, you can always ask in here. But please read the documentation in details, to get yourself started very strongly.

Comment: So it is the *best* Grid because you have used it often and because it has a documentation? Mmmkay ... :D

Comment: The OP asked for the *best* grid and you supplied your answer to that. So pragmatically you said jQGrid is the best grid. Don't get me wrong though, I am convinced you did so with the best intentions and I do not think your answer should be flagged or downvoted at all. In fact, it is the question that should be closed for being subjective. Your answer is just proof to this. But like I said, I am sure you had the best intentions and after having looked at jQGrid briefly, I am pretty sure it is a good grid - just not for the reasons you mentioned :)

Comment: @Gordon - Well thanks for your last comment, I appreciate your concerns & knowledge, from the very beginning of my tenure in SO. Also not everyone could understand the type of questions that should be asked in SO, so it will be best in the interest of everyone, if this question is not closed, & instead this conversation be closed. :) Hope you didn't mind. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

jqGrid is a jQuery flexible bare plugin(client) but there is also a PHP version of jqGrid supplied by ready server side PHP scripts (easier to use but not flexible as the bare jqGrid):

http://azgtech.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/jqgrid-php-datagrid/

### About jqGrid PHP component:

**Pros**

- A good list of different themes(good appearance)
- Light weight and Fully Ajax actions
- Inlist delete/edit (datetime edit fields are equipped by calendar)
- Add/Edit/Delete/Search buttons which open Add/Edit/Search boxes(not popups but layers) and also Paging Controller at the bottom of list
- Search Box which is equipped by calendar for datetime fields and with useful tools like dropdown for other type of fields
- Sort and Filter
- Ability for grouping list based on defined conditions
- Cross-Browser

**Cons**

- Its free version is "PHP Code Obfuscated" and hard or unable to extend
- So far I know datetime filter header is not equipped by calendar and we should enter date from left to get a result and if you enter a day or month number the search won't retrieve any result. I said "so far" because it may be customizable
- If you tested ASP.Net Telerik DataGrid, you will find a lot of points to improve in jqGrid like sort and filtering which is much better in Telerik than jqGrid

---

### **About SDTable:**

It seems the announced PROJECT is under construction because I found no download file or acceptable demo but the related website is working.

Thank you "@Knowledge Craving", I was using jqgrid-php-v1.4.1 which has some obfuscated PHP scripts and was not as flexible as I want but the main jqGrid is client side totally and more customizable and I could find a whole documentation and the bare jqGrid by the reference you offered.